# Reconstructing a matrix exponential from data

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Suppose you have a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and you are given vectors $x_i$, $y_i$ and scalars $t_i$ such that $y_i = e^{t_iA}x_i$. If you have $n$ of these vectors you should have sufficient information to solve for $A$, with the exception of certain pathological cases. Is this possible, analytically or algorithmically?

Comment: Good question. OF course, if all $t_i$ are equal, say $t_i=t_0$, then plugging in $n$ linearly independent vectors $x_i$ we recover the matrix $e^{t_0 A}$. From this (I GUESS THAT) we can solve for $A$ in some way, by taking a matrix logarithm. On the contrary, if times are allowed to vary, then things are a lot more complicated.

Comment: The answer is, of course not--but, seeing how you reacted the last time I helped you, it is wiser to stay at that.